# Using parentheses for Arithmetic inside if Statement Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

Im trying to use the distance formula inside of my javascript game, however I am having trouble using parentheses or any equivalent of them inside of an if statement.

Distance formula: distance = sqrt (x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2

```
if((sqrt(xOne-xTwo)^2+(yOne-yTwo)^2)>32){
  generate();
}

generate(){
  xOne = Math.floor((Math.random()*464)+16); 
  xTwo = Math.floor((Math.random()*464)+16); 
  yOne = Math.floor((Math.random()*464)+16); 
  yTwo = Math.floor((Math.random()*464)+16); 
{
```

Comment: Use `Math.sqrt()` and `Math.pow()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you should use `Math.sqrt` and `Math.pow`:

```
if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((xOne - xTwo), 2) + Math.pow((xOne - xTwo), 2)) > 32) {

}
```

But may I suggest a cleaner approach:

```
var a = x1 - x2
var b = y1 - y2

var c = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );
```

Comment: so why not use them?

Comment: No need to call Math.sqrt if you square the distance you compare the result with: `cmp_dist = (x1,y1,x2,y2,d) => {var a=x2-x1, b=y2-y1; return a*a+b*b>d*d;}`